# Install php-mod and php-fpm (different versions) on the same server

Tags: apache-http-server, centos, php

One of our clients has a server which is running PHP 5.3.3 (in our understanding it is mod_php, apache, Centos 6).

Is it possible to install ANOTHER php version (say PHP 8.0) in say php-fpm for a different virtual host in this machine (but keeping the mod_php for the current domains) ?

Actually we have studied by looking at examples on web, but they advised to install multiple PHP version thru php-fpm (both), but we want to know whether it is possible to do it in mod_php + php-fpm.

Just a few bullets points for guiding us is already very helpful (say the main steps, etc.)

I should be very grateful if someone can provide advice on this. Thank you.

Comment: Without knowing what OS they're running and what problems you've run into, the best answer we can give is "yes"

Comment: Apologies, the OS is Centos Linux 6.0. The problem is - the client is running an old system , but rather critical so they would like "not to touch/change" this system, but they plan to deploy a new system requiring new PHP version (PHP 8.0) - the question has been revised to make it clearer. Thanks

Comment: While it might be possible, is it _required_ that it even be the same system at all? Can the client afford a second server? (It would then be possible to eventually migrate the old system into a container within the new server, ending up with one machine again.)

Comment: CentOS 6 has reached EOL in November 2020., PHP 5.3 - in 2014. Definitely consider installing an up to date server and migrating the old one. You could even virtualize it on the new one to avoid duplicating hardware.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your valuable comments. Yes it is agreed that the current system (CentOS 6) is a bit old and it is desirable to consider using a new system on a second server. I will talk with our client to see whether they are willing to do it. Thanks a lot.